# How to deploy node js application on nginx on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx

I  have installed nginx on my windows but how can i deploy my node js application on nginx.

most of the videos are only shows on how to deploy nodejs application on nginx on linux only.

Answer (score -1):

my suggestion is that you need to use Linux Operating System for deploying the application because-

- Stability and Reliability
- Security
- Flexibility
- Free and Open Source
- Hardware Support
- Total Cost of Ownership (TCO) and Maintenance

and Linux has today become a strategic, efficient, and reliable platform for business systems at many small, medium to big companies. A larger percentage of servers powering the Internet run on a Linux-based operating system, and this has been attributed to the above key reasons.

**just checkout this link it might be helpful :)**
[https://www.digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Commentary on preferred platform; not at all helpful to the OP's question.